# Windows explorer seemingly not running on startup with Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, virus, trojan

For some strange reason, the start menu, taskbar and desktop icons are not running on my computer. I can still run task manager, and the locking screen and screensaver still work. According to the task manager, Windows explorer is running, as well as all other necessary services/processes, but I cannot open an actual explorer Windows by using the "run" function in the task manager (though, I can start almost all other applications through this function).

I have rebooted and logged off / logged on multiple times, but to no affect. I am also running an AVG full computer scan at the moment, but so far all it has found are a few Trojan horse injects, agents and crypts (not really a big deal) and a "virus found ILCrypt". Also, according to AVG the drivers for my firewall are missing, and my firewall is down. All other components and virus scan are still working fine though.

I have not downloaded anything malicious / dangerous any time recently.

If it helps, I am using a workstation PC (2x Intel Xeon 12 core 4.00 GHz) running Windows XP pro.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get rid of malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

Comment: Your infected, see my answer here...http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc/157533#157533

Comment: This might not be an infection; it happens when WINLOGON gets hung up, then Explorer is not run and the desktop is not created. I experience this with XP sometimes as well and what was described is one of the symptoms. Other common symptoms include [`xp stuck loading preferences`](https://www.google.com/search?q=xp+stuck+loading+preferences), [`xp wlnotify.dll`](https://www.google.com/search?q=xp+wlnotify.dll), and [`xp startup sound not played`](https://www.google.com/search?q=xp+startup+sound+not+played). If I ever manage to figure out what’s causing it or how to fix it, I’ll let you know.

Comment: im going to trust Synetech on this one, because i did do a complete wipe of all viruses, but to no affect when i rebooted after. considering that i then rebooted much later and everything was fine again, it seems more likely that the WINLOGON did get hung up, as said above.